# Excel comparing two column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've a data as below in excel sheet:

[image]

My question is how to write a function that so that a value in column c would check whether the value exist in column a or not, if exist then return Yes else no. Example if I enter A2 in column C, then the excel will return Yes in column D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MATCH` returns `#N/A` if it fails to find a match, better to check for the error:

So formula for D2 would be

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(C2,A:A,0)),"No","Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=IF(MATCH(C2,A:A,0)>1,"Yes","")
```